# When (if ever) disclose your identity as a reviewer?

Tags: peer-review, journals

The peer review system is in general single blinded: The reviewers will not be known by the authors of a paper by default. One reason for this is to guarantee that the reviewer can write his opinions on the paper without expecting any drawbacks whatsoever. However, I can imagine situations in which the reviewer may think about disclosing his identity:

1. The reviewer is not d'accord with the editor's decision. This happened to me once - as author: the reviewer wrote some kind of open letter to the the editor and put me and my coauthor in the cc. Basically, the reviewer complained that the editor weighted some other (unqualified) review high enough to not accept the paper.
2. The reviewer has ideas for further research based on the paper and thinks that a collaboration would be a very good idea. He could think about contacting the author directly but this would disclose his identity (in the case that the paper is not available as a preprint - which still happens sometimes). However, waiting until the paper would be published would be a waste of time.

Since I experienced 1. myself and I am thinking about 2., I would like to hear anwers to this question:

> Under what circumstances (if any) should a reviewer disclose his identity to the authors of a paper?

**Edit:** A small clarification for point 2.: First, the submitted paper is not publicly available and hence, writing to the author would disclose the reviewers identity.  Moreover, it is *not* about improving the actual paper (and wishing to become a coauthor) but about further work inspired by the paper.

In view of the current answer, I would also like to expand the current question a little bit (which is not worth a whole new question, I think):

> ... and what are arguments against disclosing the reviewers identity?

Comment: You should discuss this with the editor.

Comment: I have heard of a reviewer doing this to cut out the editor as a middle-person for simple expediency. The reviewer however, is quite senior and reasonably immune from any of the possible negative consequences.

Comment: They made an episode of NOVA about FLT  and Andrew Wiles. There was one referee per chapter. One of them says, on camera, that he did nothing that summer except go through line by line, emailing Wiles at stumbling blocks. Eventually there came a day when several contacts with Wiles did not result in a workable fix of a gap. I can't seem to remember the referee's name. 

Comment: I once met somebody who *thought* was a referee for the FLT paper. He said he was working on it, and was quite perplexed when I showed him the issue of the Annals with the paper in it, that the library had just received a few days ago.

Comment: @WillJagy: I think you are talking about Nick Katz.

Comment: I think there is no "should" on this topic: It is a personal preference.  I only review nonanonymously, which I find inclines me to care and to courtesy, whether the report is positive or negative.

Comment: I think this question is more appropriately asked at http://academia.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think it's fine to disclose your identity eventually; however, I don't think that it is ok to tell the author your identity before the journal has made a decision on the paper (unless, of course, the editor gives permission). Indeed, I could imagine it causing problems for the author at certain journals -- the editorial board might feel that it compromises your objectivity and thus be less likely to take your advice.

Comment: I once had been asked for a review by a somewhat predatory journal, and considered e-mailing the authors about this (since they probably reviewed the journal was good). But the review request e-mail claimed it was confidential, so I was afraid that doing this might breach some confidentiality law.

Answer (score 36):

Anonymity is the referee's right (or privilege), not an obligation.  I think the referee should be free to disclose his/her identity to the author.

Comment: I agree completely.

Comment: I have always just assumed this is right.  I almost never do tell an author, and I can imagine special situations where it would even be unfair to the author if I did.  But I never thought there was any general rule against it.

Answer (score 24):

On a somewhat practical -- and frighteningly co-incident -- note, just this morning a reviewer revealed his identity to me on the grounds that his own as-yet unpublished work overlaps my paper that he is currently reviewing.

As a reviewer, encountering a draft which overlaps your current project would be a bit of a nightmare scenario for a variety of straightforward reasons; I think a frank discussion with the author is mandated in such a situation so that the simultaneous development of common ideas can be properly expressed and clearly cited.

This is one situation where it seems as though the "do it blind" idea is extremely dangerous and counter-productive. You really wouldn't want to end up in a situation where you are accused of stealing ideas from unpublished work (that you were reviewing!) and then rushing your own eerily similar draft to a journal with quicker turnaround time so it gets published first. It is much better to explain the situation to both the author of that work and the editor of the journal so that everything gets sorted out transparently and amicably.

Comment: I think the reviewer here has acted wrongly. If your work was available elsewhere (on the arXiv say), they should return your paper to the editor and contact you directly. If your work was not available then they are unlucky, and should just suck it up. One defence for a reviewer would be be to adopt a policy that you only referee papers that are posted on the arXiv.

Comment: As much as I *adore* the arXiv, it is downright silly to start hunting for online preprints of each paper you are reviewing. And what's worse, often the arXiv version is not the same as the draft that reaches you. 

Comment: @Chris Godsil: what would in your opinion be the correct way to proceed if the situation would be slightly different in that the referee submitted their work slightly before the person whose overlapping paper they are now refereeing [and assume neither is available]? Pretend their own work does not exist? Reject on the grounds the result is overlaps with existing work? Neither of theses extremes seems particularly good to me.

Comment: In a slightly different direction personally I find the idea to return the paper (with a factual explanation of the situation or just so, btw) and then to pretend towards the author one just happened to have found the paper a bit odd. Since, here, one tries to get some advantage out of knowing the paper because one was (asked to be) the referee and does not even make this explicit. Or is the idea that one then says one would have been the referee. But then this seems to me like disclosing referees identity. As evidently if one would write a joint paper one would not stay referee either way.  

Comment: Pardon a question from someone in a different field: why didn't the reviewer turn down the invitation to review and say they had a conflict of interest when they saw the abstract? Was it not clear from the abstract that there was substantial overlap? Or is that not how invitations to review work in math?

Answer (score 14):

I think there are ethical issues here that other people have not brought up, even after the refereeing job is done.

By letting the author know about your (very positive?) referee report, they may feel more likely to "repay the favor" in the future.  This seems potentially problematic to me (although in many cases it won't be).  Obviously, if you recommended rejection :-( or gave an isufficiently glowing report, this seems less problematic from an ethical perspective...

That said, I have revealed that I'm the referee of various papers in the past.  Although usually because something came up in conversation and it seemed natural to mention this (ie, "I know what you are talking about, I refereed this paper of yours a while back and had a conversation with you about this topic through the editor").  To me this could still be problematic although perhaps still can be good/ok.

For example, in one case I revealed I had been the referee of a paper to the author after it had been accepted but before it had been published because I wanted to exhort the author to put the *corrected* version of the paper on the arXiv (to replace the existing version with some misleading mistakes).

Finally, in another case I revealed my identity to the author after getting permission from the editor during the referee process.  This was a case where the editors were not looking so much for my opinion of the paper in terms of quality (it was a birthday conference proceedings), but wanted a detailed report on correctness.  I asked the editors if it was ok to contact the author directly to speed up the process.

Comment: @Karl: Are you saying that birthday conference proceedings papers need not be interesting?

Comment: Certainly not! (and in many cases they have higher overall quality than the journal they are published in)  However, in this particular case the editors expressly told me that they were only looking for correctness.

Comment: Perhaps I'm mistaken, but the impression I have is that the reason some birthday conference proceedings have such fantastic papers is *not* because the referees are asked to keep things at high standards, but instead because the authors want to submit very good papers to the proceedings to honor the focus of the proceedings.

Answer (score 13):

I think PaPiro's answer is entirely correct, based on my own experiences as author, referee and editor.

One principle is that the referee is carrying out a task at the request of, and for, the editor. I would say that the the referee's task is to supply information to the editor, who will use this to decide what should be done with the paper. The standard is that the 
referees are anonymous, and if you agree to referee a paper you are accepting this constraint by default.

All correspondence between the referee and author should go through the editor. This provides the referee with protection from the author - I recall one case where an author was very vexed by a positive report, because it was felt that the report was not positive enough. It also provides the author with protection from the referee's requests, which are not always guided by the pure light of reason.

If the referee provides a substantive improvement to the paper, the authors are free to propose via the editor that the referee be added as an author. They are also free to decline.
My own view in this case is that the editor does not have a right to insist that the improvements be added, and that the final
decision should be based on the submitted paper, not on what it might have been. (Dealing with this sort of issue is why editors are so well paid, of course.)

If as referee you are unhappy with the way an editor has handled a paper, you are free to contact other members of the board.

As for Will Jagy's anecdote about Wiles, I appeal to the adage "extreme cases make bad law".

Comment: When reviewing however, be prepared for your anonymity to be compromised. I once got three reports from an editor which were PDF files labelled Smith.pdf, Jones.pdf and Bloggs.pdf where Smith, Jones and Bloggs (not their real names) are people known-to-me working in the area. 

Unless the editor was having fun, for example, by getting a grad student to write a report and then giving it the filename Gowers.pdf before sending it to the author, I now know the identity of the three referees. 

(Luckily all reports recommended acceptance!)

Comment: @Chris. "...is why editors are so well paid ..." is a joke. Isn't it?

Comment: @Denis Serre: Of course.

Comment: In reference to Gordon's comment, as a referee it is always a good idea to write your report as though the author will find out who refereed it. This will improve the tone of the report. Note though, that from I have seen authors are not good at guessing who the referee was.

Comment: Just one word: never.

Answer (score 11):

If you are sent a paper to referee that is **not publicly available**, I believe it is your duty to provide your report and then pretend you have never seen the paper, at least until it appears somewhere public. You shouldn't be thinking about proving any conjectures made in the paper or generalizing its results. You shouldn't be contemplating collaborations to extend the work. The author has chosen not to make his or her results public yet, and has the right to have this privacy maintained throughout the editorial process. So I think contacting the author in situation (2) of the original post is highly inappropriate.

Comment: I really can't understand why...It seems very silly to me to waste the opportunity to further develop the frontiers of current mathematics just because an author wants to keep the ideas for himself for a while. We cannot afford that! Mathematics should be considered universal patrimony of human kind. That kind of attitude from an author should be discouraged; it is also very narrow-minded in my opinion.

Comment: I agree with godelian! Do you think Erdos ever cared about waiting before he published something for one of his collaborators to extend one of his results?

Comment: Your answer seems to implictly assume that the author(s) made a concious choice not to make the paper publically available. Sometimes my papers are simply not available online just so. I certainly agree one must not take advantage of being a referee *at the author's expense.* But something like described can be a win-win situation.
So I agree with you (daveh) that the authors *if they wish to* have a rigth to privacy. But they might not want it. Thus, I think to try to make contact, likely prefarably via the editor, is a good idea. If they say 'not' it's 'no', but they might also be happy.

Comment: @godelian: An author submits a paper to a journal in confidence, and it is forwarded to the referee(s) in confidence. If the editor accepts the paper then the journal has the write to publish it; no-one else does. I know of at least one case where a very senior and highly regarded mathematician was very annoyed because details of their work leaked out. I do not understand why they did not want their results released earlier, but it's their choice.

Comment: @SamuelReid I was not aware that Erdos was a paragon

Comment: I see no objection to providing ones ideas anonymously as part of the referee report.  It seems part of the referee's duty to make improving comments, but not to ask for credit for them.  In the dark ages when I was young it was fairly common for an author to acknowledge helpful improvements from an anonymous referee.

I see no problem with foregoing credit for unsolicited improvements to a project in which I was not a requested collaborator.  But 
i feel kind of like a cranky old dinosaur for saying this.  

I apologize for that musty odor of formaldehyde and self righteousness.

Comment: <whinge>Roy Smith's remarks reminded me that I refereed, not that long ago, a very demanding paper where in one place (not really the heart of the main problem) I found a way to streamline things slightly. I duly mentioned this in my report and it was implemented by the authors. However, although the published version thanks the anonymous referee for "hard work and useful comments", it doesn't actually say "The original version of Proposition X was longer, and the current version is based on a suggestion of the referee".</whinge>

Comment: @Yemon, I also agonize over the consequences of this policy, but it still seems correct, even if difficult.

Comment: @Yemon, As encouragement, I know "thanks for useful comments" can mean: correcting an erroneous proof, pointing out a serious gap, making the observation for which the paper is usually cited, or essentially writing a whole chapter of my book.

But we also have exemplary models by some of the best authors and geometers alive, e.g William Fulton, in Intersection Theory, where dozens of previous workers are generously and accurately credited with important ideas.  An equally generous and scholarly example is Geometry of Algebraic Curves, by Arbarello, Cornalba, Griffiths, and Harris. Keep heart.

Comment: @godelian: An example may help. Wiles's first manuscript (the incorrect one) was not publicly circulated. Let's pretend that the preprint was "leaked," and someone else managed to plug the gap first. Wiles would then probably not get as much credit as he does today for FLT. If there's no way to prevent this kind of thing, then people may become even more secretive in their efforts to protect their access to credit. Or else fewer people will try working on high-risk projects because they know they won't get enough credit. Either way, it could have a stifling effect on the progress of math.

Answer (score 4):

This is more of a response to @Chris. The FLT case is actually useful, in that for many papers of sufficient magnitude, the author will know who the referee is, and even for papers of insufficient magnitude, getting emails saying: hey, I was looking at your preprint, and the proof of lemma x.y.z eludes me is usually a hint. Sending such email through the editor slows down the process by orders of magnitude. The suggestion to be co-author (in my experience) tends to come from the editor, not the referee, and is sufficiently often a bad idea that I think it should never be done (having it come from the authors, as Chris suggests, is a good idea, but has not happened in my experience as author, referee, or editor).

As for the OP's question:

point 2 seems moot: why should the author care that you are the referee. Just write about your great idea, and suggest a joint paper. The author may object that the paper is already submitted, but then saying that you are the referee sounds like blackmail.

point 1: This sort of action seems totally pointless. Both the referee and the author should just take note, and never submit anything to the journal as long as the bad editor is on the board.

Comment: I knew of a case where the editor slowed things down ridiculously. Paper was submitted. Somehow, I knew the author and referee. Paper was withdrawn. I found out, told the referee. Editor never told the referee the paper had been withdrawn.

Comment: Since an author can post the paper on the arXiv, thereby establishing priority, I do not feel that it is a great problem if a week or two is lost to preserve the referee's anonymity. Since the delay is caused by difficulties in the paper, there seems to be no grounds for complaint. 

Responding to @Andres Calcedo, I suspect we can all offer up horror stories of sufferings at the hands of editors. I do not see that this has a bearing on the general principles.






Comment: @Chris I agree. It was just an amusing tangentially related anecdote.

Comment: @Chris: "A week or two"? You must be living in some other, much speedier, universe.

Comment: @Igor Rivin: Well, I'm assuming it's just emails passing back and forth, the slow part would be the author formulating a response.
Very little thought should be required on the editor's part. On the other hand, I once had a paper sit on one editor's desk for a year because it had been forwarded to him without a covering letter (by another editor). But now it's all on computers and everything runs much more smoothly... :-)

Comment: @Chris: the slow part is usually the editor, since editors usually handle a lot of stuff, in addition to (sometimes) having lives, so if they are organized, they deal with this sort of week at regular intervals (say once a week or, more likely, once a month), which means that by the time the referee gets an answer, he has forgotten the question. Again, I very much hope you have had better experiences.

Comment: @Igor: I don't quite understand why you say that "point 2 is moot."  As I understand Dirk's scenario, the paper in question is not available to the general public, and the referee's ideas are prompted by the ideas in the paper.  Writing to the author about the ideas then automatically discloses the referee's identity.

Comment: @Timothy: Thanks for the clarification! Somehow it seems that I couldn't make it clear enough...

Comment: @Timothy: I see. I am so used to papers circulating in preprint form for years, that the idea of paper not being publicly available is foreign to me...

Answer (score 4):

For question 2.

According to the instructions given to referees by certain journals ... the submitted material is to be treated as privileged information.  And (one consequence) you cannot use it as a basis for your own further research.  Of course, once the paper is published, or the author otherwise releases it as a preprint, then of course you can use the information.  And in particular you could then contact the author about a collaboration.  (You need not mention that you were a referee.)

So I reiterate one of the other responses: do not do it without the approval of the editor who sent you the paper for review.

Comment: Aren't most refereed papers nowadays released as a preprint before being refereed - or in any case before the referee finishes refereeing them?

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a long comment. Concerning point 2: Here is an amusing example when the referee wanted to collaborate with the author *on the paper that he/she was refereeing*, and so contributed a two-page appendix to the paper *without disclosing their identity:*

[Real reductive Cayley groups of rank 1 and 2. 
With appendices by Dolgachev and an anonymous referee. 
J. Algebra 436 (2015), 35–60.](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=ICN&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&r=1&review_format=html&s4=borovoi&s5=dolgachev&s6=&s7=&s8=All&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq)

(Excuse me for promoting my own work...)